# Limited open redirect ideas

Tags: url-redirection

This website (example.com for confidentiality) has an odd open redirect situation. It redirects after logging in by a URL parameter like `example.com/login?returnURL=https://example.com`

I found that it allows you to change the redirect protocol to almost anything except a few windows protocols like mailto, so you can do something like:

```
example.com/login?returnURL=steam://egg.example.com
```

However, as in the example above, *.example.com must be immediately after the protocol or it doesn't work.

Any ideas on common protocols where I could make my own malicious link and it would redirect to it?

Comment: Windows protocols?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways to bypass such if it's properly validated. To know it better, you need to understand the URL architecture and how things are dine programmatically.
For example,
`http://example.com@evil.com` redirects evil.com. This is because `example.com` in this case is username (part of authority) directly supplied in URL. You can learn more about URL architecture from https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3. I'd also recommend you go through Tangled Web.
And, deoending in how it's being validated, you can also send `http://evil.com?http://example.com`. This also satisfies the condition that scheme is directly followed by `example.com`.

If you're just looking for payloads, you might find this useful;
https://github.com/cujanovic/Open-Redirect-Payloads